# Using numpy.dstack() for merging two 3D arrays but losing spatial reference.

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, numpy

The code is as following:

```
>>> temp = numpy.dstack((spi_negative,spi_positive))
>>> 
>>> temp.shape
(16, 126, 294)
>>> out_ras = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(temp,pnt,cellsize1,cellsize2,value_to_nodata=0)
... outfile = "D:/TRMM/Gurminder_SPI_TOTAL.img"
... out_ras.save(outfile)
... arcpy.DefineProjection_management(outfile, spatialref)
```

The shape is maintained and raster image is saved successfully. But the result shows both the stacked images with different position.[image]

Comment: What is the shape of `spi_negative` and `spi_positive`?

Comment: @Kersten its the same (16, 126, 294)

Comment: Are you sure? If each one of the `spi_` arrays has a shape of (16, 126, 294) the stacking was obviously unsuccessfull since it should be (32, 126, 294).